# elegant way to have sql query fail?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to schedule a query in BigQuery that is dependent on some condition. I want the scheduled query to fail/throw an error when the condition is not met, so that the scheduler will sent an email that the query failed.

I could do something like; 'SELECT 1/0 as error' or something similar but surely there is a better way to let a query fail or throw an error?

Current SQL;

```
DECLARE row_count INT64;
BEGIN
   SET row_count = ([SOME SELECT QUERY TO GET NUMBER OF ROWS]);
   IF row_count > [somenumber] THEN
      [EXECUTE SOME DEPENDANT QUERY];
   ELSE
      SELECT 1/0 as error;
   END IF;
END;
```

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#raise perhaps?

Comment: @jarlh thanks! that does the trick. Somehow didn't see that as the option I needed (even though I had this exact page open.. doh!)